# "get along" er "git along" or "go along" (does vehicular usage matter?)?

Tags: meaning, terminology, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Why is that individual (quote attached as screenshot for evidence, servant turned their back to face away before issuing the command, to/for the conductor to drive) saying "get along" and not "go along"?

Is the carraige/stagecoach the reason for why they're saying `get` instead of `go`?

Strangely wording at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_along does not by definition, but https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/git_along does by definition, and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_along definitely says "to move along or proceed".

The actual wording from reading/watching Jane Eyre (BBC) steaming from Hulu is "Get along!".

Is that just how they actually spoke back then, did the editor/transcriber/writer/subtitler/captioner act correctly or make a mistake there, did the speaker slur the command "get" with "git" (like saying "ride") because of the horses present or being around horses so much, was rider/conductor/speaker's social class/status relevant to the usage, or were other factors defining that as passing for actual functional English?

If the vehicle moved, that means the code I mean language worked?

[image: "Screenshot from 2020-07-28 09-32-07 #Quote #"get along" #lang $lang.png" taken with Ubuntu Linux "Default Screenshot Hotkey" by prosody—Gabriel C. Chrome "Fizzle" Google Chrome Theme in Purple free.]

Comment: Who is he speaking to? Does he want passengers to exit quickly? Usually *go along* means cooperate, not move.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Distinguished the individuals and the vehicle in first paragraph edit. The servant is dressed like a conductor I think, though due to being a period drama I am not 100% guaranteeing their official titles.

Comment: *Get along* means "leave." *Go along*, in the sense of leaving, means "leave *with* someone or something." Either are possible, depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mystery. "Get" is the imperative, and "along" is its adverb complement. "Get along." is still used (at least in BE) as an order commanding, usually an animal, to move. "Get" is approximately the same as "start to move."

"Go along" is not idiomatic as a command.

"Git" is a dialect version of "get".

The OED gives the non-imperative version that is used for humans:

**to get along**

> 1. intransitive. a. **To proceed, progress, advance. Also (frequently in the progressive): to depart, go on one's way, get going. Also formerly: †to go in company with.**

1897   B. Harte Three Partners vi. 271   *I must be getting along... I've got to catch a train at Three Boulders Station.*

2007   Z. Roos Sea Spray & Cherry Peppers 94   *When three of the six weeks had passed and Daniel could get along on crutches, Stuurman received his first disability pension.*

Comment: Added that meaning to https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=get_along&oldid=59864423 (I am "Categorization"), I gave my best effort, feel free to beat me to the punch and go ahead editing, I can not afford OED.com.

Answer (score 0):

One of the meanings of "to get" is without doubt "to move", "to go"; this is clear from this source: [OALD, 12](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/get?q=get). However, in this particular case, where the adverb "along" is used, the verb appears without doubt to be the phrasal verb "to get along", which means "to leave a place" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/get-along?q=get+along)).

The pronunciation "git" is meant to reproduce the popular pronunciation of the times, back then, which happens to be a modern popular pronunciation in the US, in particular   embraced  or affected by the lower class black people. However there is no such verb in British English, where "git", except as the spelling reflecting a certain unusual pronunciation is only known as the noun meaning "a stupid person" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/git?q=git)).

Comment: I've heard a variety of people say that word/pronunciation, I thought maybe a Northern/Southern US language issue? Withholding my vote only because of that part I am worried for us, maybe I should ask this/that as another question, I do not know if that word is racialized or demographics specifically, is "git" specifically (and should you mention the other variables?) A.A.V.E.?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext I can't be as categoric as calling this pronunciation racialized; let's say that I have heard it often used by black people, and that when white people used it (rare in comparison) it was often enough in a jocular fashion that I still can't quite perceive well in its implications, but, of which, I am sure, one can say that there is no direct reference to the "Black" usage of the same pronunciation.

Comment: In BE there is absolutely no "racial element" - the phrase was in use long before significant BAME immigration. "Git" is commonly heard in various parts of the UK as a regional dialect. In the US, "Git Along, Little Dogies" is a traditional cowboy song  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_Along,_Little_Dogies) - *It is believed to be a variation of a traditional Irish ballad about an old man rocking a cradle The cowboy adaptation is first mentioned in the 1893 journal of Owen Wister, author of The Virginian.*

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext there is for instance this book from John Irvin white (https://www.bing.com/search?q=John+Irwin+White&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR3A&pc=EUPP_UE00), *Git Along Little Doggies*" and a good many other instances such as this one.

Comment: I think I am a bit worried still about the wording, determining the class of the speaker as the determinant, why say "`[Y] class [Z] people`" and not "`in AAVE (African-American Vernacular English/Black English)`"?

Comment: @prosody-GabVereableContext Well, in order to define this particular type of English, the concepts of class and race are being resorted to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English):  by most **working**- and **middle**-class African Americans and some **Black** Canadians. Those terms, lower-class, working-class,  black, are not denigratory to any degree; they are terms you can still use normally. Anyway, should there be any problem and a complaint from a moderator I'll see to changing my wording according to the up to date point of view.